# Voice over Accessibility - Avoid saying button as banner used inside header

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria, screen-readers

I need help with the accessibility issue. when the buttons are used inside the header and when I navigate to button from dropdown item voice-over says save button banner. Here I need to get rid of the banner. Any ideas, please?

```
 <header>
  <img src="companylogo.svg" alt="my company name" />
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <p>Subtitle</p>
  <button role="button">
  My button
  </button>
  <label for="cars">Choose a car:</label>

<select name="cars" id="cars">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
</header>
```

Comment: Can adding `role="none"` on `<header>` solve your issue?

Comment: role="presentation" worked , Thanks @SurajBande

Comment: Please don't add `role="presentation"` to a `<header>`.  If you do that, you might as well use a `<div>` instead of a `<header>`.

Comment: @slugolicious Thanks for letting me know . this is the issue only with voice over hence we dont want to handle this. because it is working fine with JAWS and also working fine with iOS mobile safari browser hence not resolving it. However thank you so much for letting me know

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing you need to do here as it is expected behaviour.

A "banner" is the older name for `<header>` so it is just telling you that the button is located within the banner landmark.

Using `<header>` is effectively the same as pre html5 where you would use `role="banner"` so that is why it is announced like this.

You can change screen reader settings to be less verbose, but that is a personal choice not a markup one!